# working with m:m relationships in eloquent outside laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I have been able to set up a m:m relationship in eloquent outside laravel and retrieve records but I have no idea how to add a new record as you dont create the pivot table in the code.

If these are my classes, how would i add a new instance to the M:M relationship between author and publisher?

```
<?php

include 'eloquent_database.php';
class Publisher extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'publisher';
        protected $primaryKey = 'publisher_id';

       public function authors (){
           return $this->belongsToMany('Author', 'author_publisher', 'publisher_id', 'author_id');
       }
}  

class Book extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'book';
        protected $primaryKey = 'book_id';

       public function author() {
           //related table name, pk in current table, 
           return $this->belongsTo('Author',  'author_id');
       }
}  
// Create the company model
class Author extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'author';
    protected $primaryKey = 'author_id';

    public function books()
    {
        //related table, fk IN related table, 
        return $this->hasMany('Book', 'author_id');
    }

 public function publishers (){
           return $this->belongsToMany('Publisher', 'author_publisher',  'author_id', 'publisher_id');
       }

}
```

I would also need to know how to delete one too. I have seen this documentation http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables but i dont really follow it

Id really appreicate an exxample of how to add and delete a new instance. Also onine there seeems to be so many different versions its hard to find which docs to follow as the code i have works but i didnt get it from the docs - just trial and error

Thanks a lot in advance

## edit:

in repsonse to Rays comment i do have a pivot table in the database called author_publisher with author id and publisher id but i have no idea how to work with this pivot table. Do i have to create a class for it? I dont really understand

Here is a reference to said table in the code above
 return $this->belongsToMany('Author', 'author_publisher', 'publisher_id', 'author_id');

Answer (score 0):

1. When having a M:M relationship, make sure you have a table that translates the relationship between author and publisher. An example table could be composed of entries including both author_id and publisher_id. From what you have provided, you lack such a table.
2. There's another case if you do not have such a table. In order for such a M:M relationship to work, the author table must contain a column called "publisher_id" for simplicity. Likewise the publisher table must contain a column called "author_id". Then in the author model, return $this->hasMany('Publisher', 'author_id') and in the publisher model, return $this->hasMany('Author', 'publisher_id'). You should get the correct answer.